# Overcall of 3S over 1C opening, what does it show? (assuming bidding system SAYC)

Tags: bridge, bidding

I assumed it was 10+pts, and 7 Spade suit -- am I correct?

Comment: This question isn't going to be answerable unless you give more details about the bidding system that you were using.

Comment: @bwarner: edited my answer...

Comment: What was the vulnerability? Who was dealer? Was either partnership playing a strong club system? The answer to all of these questions will weigh in on the fine details of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jump overcall is [pre-emptive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preempt) and generally shows the same values as a pre-emptive opening bid.

So in this case 3S could show as little as 6 HCP with 7 spades.

Comment: the first sentence of your answer is what i was missing. Thanks